# get data, between 2 strings using python and re

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, python-re

with the following text:

```
Style No. Pic Color Size Qty Unit Price Amount
T5890
NAVY STRIPE/… 0 $10.00 $0.00
BACK
ORDERED
NAVY STRIPE/… 6 $10.00 $60.00
BACK
ORDERED
NAVY STRIPE/… 6 $10.00 $60.00
BACK
ORDERED
NAVY STRIPE/… 0 $10.00 $0.00
BACK
ORDERED
NAVY/RED 0 $10.00 $0.00
BACK
ORDERED
NAVY/RED 6 $10.00 $60.00
BACK
ORDERED
D7077
IVORY/BURG… 0 $11.00 $0.00
D7077
BACK
ORDERED
IVORY/BURG… 0 $11.00 $0.00
BACK
ORDERED
IVORY/BURG… 6 $11.00 $66.00
BACK
ORDERED
IVORY/CHAR… 6 $11.00 $66.00
BACK
ORDERED
D7110
BURGUNDY 6 $17.50 $105.00
D7110
BACK
ORDERED
JADE 12 $17.50 $210.00
BACK
ORDERED
MUSTARD 6 $17.50 $105.00
BACK
ORDERED
T5895
BURGUNDY 6 $10.50 $63.00
T5895
BACK
ORDERED
MOCHA 6 $10.50 $63.00
BACK
ORDERED
NAVY 6 $10.50 $63.00
BACK
ORDERED
1/211/14/2019 Order Detail
```

Using the following iten_no

```
item_numbers = ['T5890', 'D7077', 'D7110', 'T5895']
```

I've been strugling getting colors for every item_number, also tried to use the previous item_number to get all the text between the previous and the actual item_number, but i wasnt succesful; the output of this shoud be:

{
'item_no' : 'T5890',
'color' : [
'NAVY STRIPE/…',
'NAVY STRIPE/…',
'NAVY STRIPE/…',
'NAVY STRIPE/…',
'NAVY/RED',
'NAVY/RED'
]
},
{
'item_no' : 'D7077',
'color' : [
'IVORY/BURG…',
'IVORY/BURG…',
'IVORY/BURG…',
'NAVY STRIPE/…',
'IVORY/CHAR…'
]
},
{
'item_no' : 'D7110',
'color' : [
'JADE',
'MUSTARD',
'BURGUNDY'
]
},
{
'item_no' : 'T5895',
'color' : [
'MOCHA',
'NAVY'
]
}

Any info that you can provide me will be highly apretiated.

Best regards.

Comment: try the result, I've provided

Comment: didn't get, why burgundy moved to d7110 and not moved to t5895

Comment: have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try that out:

```
result = []
temp_nums = []
numbers = list(set(re.findall('[A-Z]\d+', need_to_parse_string)))
temp_key = ''
for item in aaa.split('\n')[1:-2]:
    if item in numbers and item not in temp_nums:
        temp_key = item
        temp_nums.append(item)
        result.append({'item_co': item, 'color': []})
    elif item in numbers and item != temp_key:
        temp_key = item
    elif item not in ['ORDERED', 'BACK'] and item not in numbers:
        result[temp_nums.index(temp_key)]['color'].append(re.split('\s\d', item)[0])

for h in result:
    print(h)
```

where need_to_parse_string - variable where stored required to parse string

It's a bit meaty and have different result from yours, but visible, it works ok

numbers generated from the string, as well, but that step can be removed